# What is the meaning behind: ''Mind your Ps and Q's" - how did it originate?

Tags: meaning, etymology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does it mean to mind your P's and Q's?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11997/what-does-it-mean-to-mind-your-ps-and-qs)

I've heard mothers using this on the playground when talking to their children, but not sure what point they were trying to make to them?